# Responsive Tabs with Multiple Sub Level CSS Help Needed

Tags: css, tabs, responsive, multi-level

I need help in creating tabs with multiple sub level of tabs, found this its perfect in every way but it does not have multiple sub tabs level. Can you help me in its css:

https://www.cssscript.com/demo/create-responsive-tabs-component-using-css-radio-input/

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, and include your code.

Comment: I can share you the previous code, need this result actually:

http://tmdesignz.com/tm-project-client-work-phase-two/plastech-autosave2/business.html

Comment: I have tried this:

http://tmdesignz.com/autosafe-newcode/about.html

Now for next page as shown in my previous comment need sub tab level with same css code.

Comment: @pjones235 please check my comments

Answer (score 0):

Its done I have cloned the tab css and created sub-tab same code but two different names. It worked.